# PL/SQL query for statistical report?

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I have some experience querying MySQL database and I'm trying to learn how to do the same in Oracle. How hard is tI have theoretical question. Let's say I have a DEMOGRAPHICS table with the following columns: DATE_OF_BIRTH, GENDER, RACE, ETHNICITY. And a CAR table that has a column MAKE that lists different makes of the car (Toyota, Ford and etc). How would I create a statistical report that would list each car make and corresponding percentage rate in columns MALE, FEMALE, WHITE, ASIAN, BLACK, HISPANIC, NOT HISPANIC, and two age range columns (18 - 30 and 50-70). Percentages should be rounded up to 2 decimal places. It should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEllW.jpg)
I will appreciate any help including references to similar queries.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some more information required.
WHITE, ASIAN, BLACK <== are these falling under RACE column
HISPANIC, NOT HISPANIC <== are these falling under ETHNICITY column

Comment: Thank you for the reply! WHITE, ASIAN, BLACK are under RACE, HISPANIC, NOT HISPANIC are under ETHNICITY. Why did you drop both tables in the beginning? Let's say I have thousands of listings in both tables, it won't be efficient to insert each of them one by one into a new table.

Comment: The drop is not necessary, but since i already had a table called demographics in my schema, i dropped it

Answer (score 0):

```
 drop table demographics

 drop table car

 create table car(MAKE_ID number primary key, MAKE varchar2(30));

 create table demographics(DATE_OF_BIRTH date , GENDER varchar2(10), RACE varchar2(30), ETHNICITY varchar2(30), MAKE_ID references car);

 --insert into car table
 insert into car values(1,'Toyota');
 insert into car values(2,'Ford');
 insert into car values(3,'GM');

 --inserts 1000 rows into the demographics table
 insert into demographics
 select trunc(sysdate) - level as dob
        ,case when mod(level,2)=0 then 'MALE' else 'FEMALE' end as gender
        ,case when mod(level,2)=0 then 'WHITE' else 'BLACK' end as race
        ,case when mod(level,4)=0 then 'ASIAN'
              when mod(level,3)=0 then 'HISPANIC'
              when mod(level,2)=0 then 'NOT HISPANIC'
              else 'LATINO'
         end as ethnicity 
        ,case when mod(level,3)=0 then 3
              when mod(level,2)=0 then 2
              when mod(level,1)=0 then 1
         end as make_id     
 from dual
 connect by level<=1000;


 select make
        ,round((cnt_MAKE/tot_cnt)*100,2) as MALE_PERCENT
     ,round((cnt_MAKE/tot_cnt)*100,2) as FEMALE_PERCENT
 from(       
 select a.make
        ,count(case when b.gender ='MALE' then 1 end) as cnt_MALE
        ,count(case when b.gender ='FEMALE' then 1 end) as cnt_FEMALE
        ,count(case when b.race ='WHITE' then 1 end) as cnt_WHITE
        ,count(case when b.ethnicity ='ASIAN' then 1 end) as cnt_ASIAN
        ,count(case when  b.race ='BLACK' then 1 end) as cnt_BLACK
        ,count(case when b.ethnicity ='HISPANIC' then 1 end) as cnt_HISPANIC
        ,count(case when b.ethnicity ='NOT HISPANIC' then 1 end) as cnt_NOT_HISPANIC
        ,count(*) as tot_cnt        
   from car a
   join demographics b
     on a.make_id=b.make_id
 group by a.make  
 )
```